# Collapse Sidebar in MVC Layout

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to expand and collapse a Sidebar in my MVC Layout.  I'm using slight variation of the example found here: [enter link description here](http://www.bootply.com/113767#.)

The problem is that once the sidebar collapses, the content of my 'View" does not expand.  Is it possible to do this?  If so, does anyone know of a code example where this sort of thing works in MVC?

I have tried implementing Artanis' suggestion but it is still not working.  Here is the code in my _Layout.cshtml page:

```
  <div class="one-row-location">
    @RenderBody()
    <div class="sidebar-nav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 content">
                    <p class="pull-left">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
                    </p>

                </div><!--/span-->

            </div><!--/row-->

        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div>
```

Here is what is in my Index.cshtml page (which is just junk to see if the page content expands):

```
<div class="location-field">
This is a test.<input id="Text1" type="text" />
<br />
this is another test!
<br />
And another
<br />
```

Here is what is in my CSS file:

```
    .one-row-location {
  width: 100%; 
    display: table;
}
.location-field{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width: 2000px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: table-cell;
```

I feel as though I'm close, but I'm obviously missing or not understanding something.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah its possible. But you will need to show your code in order for anyone to help. Just curious, is your view a partial view? And is it being loaded via Ajax?

Comment: Mark - what's the difference if content is static or dynamically loaded via AJAX? This is pure CSS question, see my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `display: table` for container DIV and `display: table-cell` for two children DIVs (one for sidebar, other for content). Sidebar DIV can have fixed width (can be animated by using jQuery toggle between, say, 200px (sidebar open) and 0px (sidebar collapsed)), but content DIV should have no width set, which means it will expand to rest of available space because of `display: table-cell`.

This is fiddle I made to illustrate this effect for different question yesterday. In this example icon for input field have defined width, but input field will expand regardless of container dimensions. In your case only difference is that container DIV will be 100% of screen width.

http://jsfiddle.net/p0s8yad7/3/

HTML

```
    <div class="one-row-location">
    <div class="location-icon"><img src="http://oi62.tinypic.com/10ng7b5.jpg"></div>
          <div class="location-field"><input  class="input-label inputlocation" type="text" name="geolocation" id="geolocation" placeholder="Lokation" value="" />
        </div>

</div>
```

And CSS

```
.one-row-location {
  width: 80%;  // For demonstartion purposes - this width can be whatever is needed
  display: table;
}
.location-field{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.inputlocation{
    font-size:14px;
    color:#99999f;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    font-style: italic;
    height:27px;
    width:100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.location-icon {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 29px;
    height:33px;
}
```